# Symfony2 Translations in StreamedResponse

Tags: php, symfony

I've got a batch processing/rendering task. This is done by streaming data from the database formatting it in the desired way and streaming it to the client via `StreamedResponse`. I want the processing and streaming to be as light as possible.

```
$responseStream->setCallback(function () use ($statement) {
  echo '{"data":[';
  $firstRow = $statement->fetch();
  echo json_encode(arrayFromRow($firstRow));
    while (is_object($statement) AND ($row = $statement->fetch()) !== FALSE) {
      echo ',';
      echo json_encode(arrayFromRow($row));
      }
      echo ']}';
   });
```

This is the stream and works fine. I want to add translations to the `arrayFromRow` function. Could you point me to some symfony2 doc for programmatic access to the message files? Is there an API for this?

Thanks

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set

```
 $translator=$this->get('translator');
```

In your action, and then use it in your callback functio, the same way you use your `$statement`